# Question about the definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question about how this theorem interacts with the definition of continuity in an example $f(x) = x^2$.

**Theorem:** If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $0 \leq a < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, then $a = 0$.

**Definition:** Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $f\colon A \to \mathbb{R}$, and $c \in A$. We say that $f$ is *continuous at $c$* if given any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x\in A$ such that $|x-c| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.

I picked $f(x) = x^2$ because it is pretty clearly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. If I consider $f$ being continuous at $c=0$, then $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$. Since $$f(c) = f(0) = 0^2 = 0$$ the inequality becomes $$ |f(x) - 0| < \epsilon$$

Then apply the theorem and $f(x) = 0$ because $\epsilon$ was an arbitrary positive number. This doesn't make sense though because consider $f(1) = 1^2 = 1$. Then $|1| < \epsilon$ and obviously $f(x)$ is not 0.  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: $|1|$ is certainly not less than $\epsilon$ for **every** $\epsilon>0$, so the theorem doesn’t apply.

Comment: @EvanKim You are confusing a bit the notion of continuity... It is not true that $|f(x)-c| < \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon >0$. If $f$ is continuous, for any given $\varepsilon>0$ you are able to find some $x's$ ( the ones satisfying $|x-c|< \delta$) that satisfy $|f(x)-c|< \varepsilon$.

Comment: @downvoters This question is valuable because it reveals a conceptual misunderstanding.  Quantifiers and conditionals are hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You skipped the part where, given $\epsilon>0$, “*there exists* $\delta > 0$ such that **if** $|x-c|< \delta$, **then** $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.”

If $\epsilon$ is small, the necessary $\delta$ will probably be much less than $1$.  So $x=1$ would likely not satisfy $|x| < \delta$, meaning we can't conclude that $|f(1)| < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $f$ is continuous at $0$, but that does *not* mean that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$ for each $\varepsilon>0$. Actually, this is meaningless, since you say nothing about $x$. It surely is *not* true that for each $\varepsilon>0$ and for each $x\in\Bbb R$, $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$. Continuity at $0$ means that, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that, when $|x|<\delta$, $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$. But it does *not* mean that there is a $x\in\Bbb R$ such that, for each $\varepsilon>0$, $|f(x)-f(0)|<\varepsilon$ (other than $x=0$, of course).

Answer (score 1):

In the theorem, $ a$ does not depend on $ \epsilon$ . Given $ a$  then

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\; 0\le a < \epsilon \;\; \implies a=0$$
but in the definition of continuity, 
You should write,
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\; \exists \delta_{\epsilon}>0 $$
such that

$$\forall x\in A$$
$$|x - c|<\delta_{\epsilon} \;\; \implies \;\;| f(x) - f(c) |<\epsilon$$
And In your special case,

$$|x|<\delta_{\epsilon}\;\; \implies \;\; |f(x)|<\epsilon$$

The condition $ |f(x)|<\epsilon $ is satisfied only if $ |x|<\delta_{\epsilon}$